# Uncover items piecewise

Tags: beamer, lists, itemize, overlays

I would like to uncover items piecewise, but have two items appear at the same time. I use the beameruserguide page 215 to do so as

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\frame{
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item First point
        \item[<.->] Second point
        \item Third point
    \end{itemize}
}

\end{document}
```

To create output, I have used both

```
 latex test.tex
 dvips test.dvi
```

and

```
 pdflatex test.tex
```

For the second point, the item symbol (a triangle) has turned into an upside-down exclamation mark followed by a period and a dash (.-) and ended by an upside-down question mark.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: I don't know if that's relevant, but the same [beamer user guide](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf), page 35, reads: "Do not uncover lists piecewise."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood, you want `beamer` to show only **First item** and then **Second item** and **Third item**?

If yes, here the correct code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{itemize}[<+->]
        \item First point
        \item Second point
        \item<.-> Third point
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Looks like the documentation is wrong, I'm going to report this to the creator.

Answer (score 4):

Remove the spurious square brackets from `\item`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}

\frame{
 \begin{itemize}[<+->]
 \item First point
 \item<.-> Second point
  \item Third point
  \end{itemize}
   }

\end{document}
```